# Can Chrome be prevented from autocorrecting search strings?

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know how I can prevent Chrome from automatically correcting my search string? For example, say I want to search Google (using the address bar) for "C# webclient", it will correct it to "C/# webclient" which is very annoying. Does anyone know how I can disable this? Obviously Googling "webclient C#" works fine, but it's just a pain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really.

Wrench Icon > Settings > Advanced Settings (text link at the bottom of the settings page) > Deselect "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. After doing it, I also restarted my browser and it still added the slash between 'C' and '#'.

Comment: Perhaps try disabling "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" also? Edit: What platform are you on? I just tried the same search as you listed and it worked fine for me, with autocorrect options enabled. Edit 2: Have you tried disabling all extensions (if you have any)?

Comment: I am on Windows 7, and disabling all extensions also doesn't work.

Comment: I presume you're running the latest build of chrome? I just tried this on one of my other machines and it doesn't do it on that one either...

Comment: Yes I am on the latest version of Chrome. It also does this to a friend of mine (who is also on the latest version), so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: Tried it on Chrome at my office as well - no problems there either. How strange! Anything else abnormal about your Chrome installation?

Comment: Well a couple days ago, anything that I would search using the address bar would say, "did you mean to go to pizza/" (if I searched pizza). It stopped doing that around 5 days ago.

Comment: I'd consider that a pretty major problem (not to mention an odd one)! Have you done a Spyware/Adware scan?

Comment: No I have not recently done one, and I currently am which has detected 8 so far 0_o Here is a picture on how it detects the '#' as a slash:
http://i.imgur.com/4A897.png

Comment: I'm betting that's the cause of your problem. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Put your search string in **single or double quotes** exactly like this, for example: "C# webclient" (with the quotes included).

Comment: Yes I could, but that's just a pain. I want to just stop Chrome from doing that...